# "Table tr" , "table tbody", not working on javascript only works "table"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really can't see why my code doesn't work as expected. I want to show a image (from a JSON I loaded previously) when I mouse over each row of my table. Each image is different depending on the row and I want to show them outside of the table in another element.

At this moment I have the table with the hover and I can load a image *(I' m using the same image for all the rows just to try)* but it affects to the whole element, including the table head. I want to avoid the hover on the head but it only works with "tblList", and each time I try to change it to "tblList tr", "tblList tbody" or similar it doesn't work. Please if you see any solution let me know. Thanks!

EDITED: **If if copy the hover and paste them into my list function, at the end, it works with : "tblList .tablerow "**. Still can't understand why if it's outside it doesn't work.

THE HTML:

```
 <article class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" id="tblList">
  </table>
  </article>
```

The JS :

```
 $("#tblList").hover(function() {
        var piso1 = JSON.parse(tbPisos[0]);
        $('#displayDiv img').attr("src", piso1.Foto);

    }, function(){
        $('#displayDiv img').attr("src", null);
    });
```

the list function :

```
function List(){
    $("#tblList").html("");
    $("#tblList").html(
        "<thead>"+
       "<tr>"+
        //"<th></th>"+
        "<th>Precio</th>"+
        "<th>Direccion</th>"+
        "<th>Ciudad</th>"+
        "<th>Fecha</th>"+
        "<th>Estado</th>"+
        "</tr>"+
        "</thead>"+
        "<tbody>"+
        "</tbody>"
    );


    for(var i in tbPisos){
        var pisos= JSON.parse(tbPisos[i]);
        $("#tblList tbody").append("<tr class ='table-row'>"+"td"+
           // "<td>"+pisos.ID+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+pisos.Precio+ " €"+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+pisos.Direccion+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+pisos.Ciudad+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+pisos.Anyo+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+pisos.Estado+"</td>" +
            +"</tr>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you're able to perform hover event on parent but not on it's childrens.

Use **`on()`** to bind an event on dynamically appended elements.

And **`Child Selector (“parent > child”)`** to perform an event on child under a particular parent.

```
$('body').on('hover', "#tblList > tbody", (function() {
        var piso1 = JSON.parse(tbPisos[0]);
        $('#displayDiv img').attr("src", piso1.Foto);
    }, function(){
        $('#displayDiv img').attr("src", null);
    }
});
```

OR

```
$('#tblList').on('hover', 'tbody', (function() {
          var piso1 = JSON.parse(tbPisos[0]);
          $('#displayDiv img').attr("src", piso1.Foto);
      }, function(){
          $('#displayDiv img').attr("src", null);
      }
});
```

And please make sure that you're getting value of `var piso1 = JSON.parse(tbPisos[0]);` in your hover function and check your console if it gives any errors.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This solution doesn't work either for me, but I move the hover code inside the List function and apparently it works. I can't see why if it's outside it does nothing...

Comment: You need to use `on()` method to bind an event on dynamically added HTML elements.

Comment: And make sure that you're getting value of `var piso1 = JSON.parse(tbPisos[0]);` `piso1.Foto` in your hover function and check your console if you can see any errors.

Comment: Sure, the value is correct, I can load the image from the JSON, I will focus to understand on() method. I debugged my code with your solution but it doesn't reach the hover.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle to check the exact problem ?

Comment: Also you should put your code into `$(document).ready(function(){ //your code })`